# Having issues with page styling w/ radio buttons & checkboxes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to line up 3 or more checkboxes or radio buttons vertically. I can get two to work, but a third of either breaks the design. I have the code so anyone can see what I'm talking about

https://codepen.io/adgoetz89/pen/jJROOm

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Margarine');
body {
  background: linear-gradient(195deg, #4e9131, #527842, #46941c, #41633c);
}

.content {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(95deg, #a8ff79, #7cc75a);
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#title {
  font-family: Margarine;
  font-size: 42px;
}

p {
  font-family: Margarine;
}

label {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  clear: left;
}

input,
textarea,
select {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#interest-label {
  ;
}

#submit-form {
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="content">
      <h1 id="title">Take our survey!</h1>
      <article>
        <p id="description">We appreaciate your service! If you would like, please let us know how we are doing by filling out our survey.</p>
      </article>

      <form action="index.html" method="post" id="survey-form">

        <Section id="contactinfo">
          <div>
            <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" id="name" required>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label id="email-label" for="email">E-Mail:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" id="email" required>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label id="number-label" for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label id="age-label" for="phone">Age:</label>
            <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age" min="18" max="100" id="number">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label id="interest-label" for="interest">Interest:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="stock1" value="old">Old stock<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="stock2" value="new">New stock<br>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label id="gender-label" for="gender">Gender:</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
          </div>
        </section>

        <section id="approval">
          <div>
            <label id="ratinglabel" for="rating">Order quality:</label>
            <select name="rating" id="dropdown">
              <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
              <option value="good">Good</option>
              <option value="fair">Fair</option>
              <option value="poor">Poor</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section id="comments">
          <div>
            <label id="messagelabel" for="message">Comments:</label>
            <textarea name="message" rows=4 cols=3 0 id="textinput">
            </textarea>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section id="submission">
          <div id="submit-form">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
          </div>
        </section>

      </form>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

```
#main {
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica;
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #f5c5ba,
#f5d4ba, #f5e2ba);
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center; }
```

As soon as I add a third checkbox or radio button the code messes up

Comment: The problem is due to the fact that the labels are simply floated. Two checkboxes/radios still generate little enough “height” to be kept next to the labels, but any more are allowed to flow under it. One easy fix would be the put the inputs into an additional grouping container div, and have that set to `display:inline-block`.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] within the question itself - links to codepen are nice, but unless all the code necessary to replicate the issue is within the question, then the question is off topic

Comment: dont use <br>   search for how to set display in css

Answer (score 0):

You could try using display: inline-flex. However, this is not supported in older versions of IE nor Opera

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Margarine');

body {
  background: linear-gradient(195deg, #4e9131, #527842, #46941c, #41633c);
}

.content {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(95deg, #a8ff79, #7cc75a);
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#title {
  font-family: Margarine;
  font-size: 42px;
}

p {
  font-family: Margarine;
}

label {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  clear: left;
}

input, textarea, select {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#submit-form {
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.radio-group {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.checkbox-group{
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <main>
    <div class="content">
      <h1 id="title">Take our survey!</h1>
      <article>
        <p id="description">We appreaciate your service! If you would like, please let us know
        how we are doing by filling out our survey.</p>
      </article>

      <form action="index.html" method="post" id="survey-form">

        <Section id="contactinfo">
          <div>
            <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" id="name" required>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label id="email-label" for="email">E-Mail:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" id="email" required>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label id="number-label" for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label id="age-label" for="phone">Age:</label>
            <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age"
            min="18" max="100" id="number">
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox-group">
            <label id="interest-label" for="interest">Interest:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="stock1" value="old">Old stock<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="stock2" value="new">New stock<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="stock3" value="foo">Foo stock<br>

          </div>
          <div class="radio-group">
            <label id="gender-label" for="gender">Gender:</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other

          </div>
        </section>

        <section id="approval">
          <div>
            <label id="ratinglabel" for="rating">Order quality:</label>
            <select name="rating" id="dropdown">
              <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
              <option value="good">Good</option>
              <option value="fair">Fair</option>
              <option value="poor">Poor</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section id="comments">
          <div>
          <label id="messagelabel" for="message">Comments:</label>
            <textarea name="message"
            rows = 4 cols = 30 id="textinput">
            </textarea>
          </div>
        </section>

      <section id="submission">
        <div id="submit-form">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
        </div>
      </section>

      </form>
    </div>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

04FS was correct that I needed to put the labels within a div, and style them with display: inline-flex. Good explanation as well, thank you for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before wrap your fields with a span. I generally like to stack my labels on top so it isn't such a hassle to make responsive, but this should get you started.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Margarine');
    body {
      background: linear-gradient(195deg, #4e9131, #527842, #46941c, #41633c);
    }
    
    .content {
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: auto;
      background: linear-gradient(95deg, #a8ff79, #7cc75a);
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    #title {
      font-family: Margarine;
      font-size: 42px;
    }
    
    p {
      font-family: Margarine;
    }
    
    label {
      float: left;
      padding-right: 10px;
      width: 100px;
      text-align: right;
      clear: left;
    }
    
    #submit-form {
      margin-left: 100px;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    span.value {
      display: block;
      padding-left: 110px;
    }
    
    label.inline {
      display: inline;
      float: none;
    }
    
    input[type=checkbox],
    input[type=radio] {
      display: inline;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"],
    input[type="radio"] {
      margin: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
    }
    
    form div {
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
  </style>
  <html>

  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="content">
        <h1 id="title">Take our survey!</h1>
        <article>
          <p id="description">We appreaciate your service! If you would like, please let us know how we are doing by filling out our survey.</p>
        </article>
        <form action="index.html" method="post" id="survey-form">
          <section id="contactinfo">
            <div>
              <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" id="name" required>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label id="email-label" for="email">E-Mail:</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" id="email" required>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label id="number-label" for="phone">Phone:</label>
              <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
            </div>
            <div>
              <label id="age-label" for="phone">Age:</label>
              <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age" min="18" max="100" id="number">
            </div>
            <div>
              <label id="interest-label" for="interest">Interest:</label>
              <span class="value">
     <input type="checkbox" name="stock1" value="old">
     <label class="inline">Old stock</label>
     </span>
              <span class="value">
     <input type="checkbox" name="stock2" value="new">
     <label class="inline">New stock</label>
     </span>
              <span class="value">
     <input type="checkbox" name="stock3" value="both">
     <label class="inline">Old and New stock</label>
     </span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label id="gender-label" for="gender">Gender:</label>
              <span class="value">
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
     <label class="inline">Male</label>
     </span> <span class="value">
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
     <label class="inline">Female</label>
     </span> <span class="value">
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="neither">
     <label class="inline">N/A</label>
     </span> </div>
          </section>
          <section id="approval">
            <div>
              <label id="ratinglabel" for="rating">Order quality:</label>
              <select name="rating" id="dropdown">
                <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
                <option value="good">Good</option>
                <option value="fair">Fair</option>
                <option value="poor">Poor</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section id="comments">
            <div>
              <label id="messagelabel" for="message">Comments:</label>
              <textarea name="message" rows=4 cols=3 0 id="textinput">
            </textarea>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section id="submission">
            <div id="submit-form">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
            </div>
          </section>
        </form>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>

  </html>

</body>

</html>
```